# Assigning ArrayList value into a Variable

Tags: java, checkbox, arraylist

I am having a problem on how can I pass all values of an arrayList in the variable. Is there a way I can acquire all values of different radio button into a single variable. Here's my program with comment

```
ArrayList < String > list1 = new ArrayList < String > ();
String rg1 = "*";
String rg2 = "*";
String rg4 = "*";
String rg5 = "*";
list1 = "*"; // Getting error here it only accepts string , how  declare list1 with ArrayList
theFilter[5] = "0";
if (cbRegAffil.isChecked()) {
    int reg = rgRegAffil.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rBtReg = (RadioButton) dia.findViewById(reg);
    rg1 = (String) rBtReg.getText();

}
if (cbAdmin.isChecked()) {
    int adm = rgAdmin.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rBtAdm = (RadioButton) dia.findViewById(adm);
    rg2 = (String) rBtAdm.getText();
}

if (cbAmbience.isChecked()) {
    int amb = rgAmbience.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rBtAmbience = (RadioButton) dia.findViewById(amb);
    rg4 = (String) rBtAmbience.getText();
}
if (cbTuition.isChecked()) {
    theFilter[5] = spin.getSelectedItem()
        .toString();
}

if (cbSpecialty.isChecked()) {
    int spec = rgSpecialty.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int spec2 = rgSpecialty2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rBtSpec = (RadioButton) dia.findViewById(spec);
    RadioButton rBtSpec2 = (RadioButton) dia.findViewById(spec2);
    list1.add((String) rBtSpec.getText());
    list1.add((String) rBtSpec2.getText());

}

TuitionFee = Integer.parseInt(theFilter[5]);
theFilter[0] = rg1;
theFilter[1] = rg2;
theFilter[3] = rg4;
theFilter[4] = rg5;
theFilter[6] = list1; // getting error within this part, how can I assign arrayList values here ?
fragment = new SchoolListFragmentFilter();
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
dia.dismiss();
```

Here's where I filter this values from radio buttons

```
if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[6])
```

Here's the additional program in order to filter sReg and select all from the rest.

```
(sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[0])
                && ((String)thisFilter[1]).equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && ((String)thisFilter[3]).equalsIgnoreCase("*") 
                && amountTF == 0
                && ((String)thisFilter[4]).equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && ((String)thisFilter[6]).equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
```

Comment: You might want to use the `add()` method. `list1.add("*");`

Comment: Is theFilter[5] is string.

Comment: public static String theFilter[] = new String[6]; it's here sir

Comment: it should be like theFilter[5]=(String)list1.get(0);//getting a value from list object based on index '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `list1 = "*";` with `list1.add("*");`

Or you can do it in the constructor like this:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("val1", "val2", "val3"));
```

This `theFilter[6] = list1;` is now possible with the edit below.

Edit:

Replace String theFilter[]=newString[6] by a `Object theFilter[]=new Object[6]` and

```
if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[6])
```

by:

```
if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[4])
                && filtered(sSpecialty[loop][subloop], (List<String>)thisFilter[6]))
```

and your filtered method:

```
private boolean filteredOne(String val, List<String> values) {
  boolean b = false;
  for(String s:values) {
    b |= s.equalsIgnoreCase(val);
  }
  return b;// true if one is equal
}

private boolean filteredAll(String val, List<String> values) {
  boolean b = true;
  for(String s:values) {
    b &= s.equalsIgnoreCase(val);
  }
  return b;// true if all are equal
}
```

Comment: It works sir , how about on the lower part of the program ? Am getting error also there

Comment: does it mean I can only select 1 value from my ArrayList ? Is there a way I can acquire all values and filter a 2d array ? I'll edit my post where I use this Filter

Comment: @carljohnsantos: with some changes (see edit) it is possible. I leave the testing and error handling to you. Good luck :)

Comment: It works now sir , but when I launch my app , it crushes because of this part && filtered(sSpecialty[loop][subloop], (List<String>)thisFilter[6])) it says java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List. Sorry sir , this is my first time creating android application and also my first time encountering these problems.

Comment: @carljohnsantos: did you change String theFilter[] with Object theFilter[]? And used theFilter[6]=list1;? BTW. you should declare list1 as a List<String>, not an ArrayList<String>

Comment: It completely works now sir , this is the last requirements for me in my thesis to select multiple Specialties . You're the best .

Comment: @carljohnsantos: your welcome. You should accept this as the answer then, so others can see that your problem is solved.

Comment: Sir can I have another question ? I have edited my post .

Comment: Same error in this part java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
 && ((String)thisFilter[6]).equalsIgnoreCase("*") , is my strcuture correct ?

Comment: @carljohnsantos: it is hard to say. You should write a mcve (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) and probably ask a new question.

Comment: It's really hard for me to express so no one is responding , sir can you check it out ? because you're the one closest to understand my program .

Comment: It is deleted (just came back from lunch).

Comment: I deleted it because i can't explain it any further , what I did is to delete this line  && ((String)thisFilter[6]).equalsIgnoreCase("*") , do you think there will be issue ? Filtering sReg and select all from the rest ?

Comment: And also sir , can you update the filter method. when I execute it , if one value from the list satisifies it will display the list disregarding the other value, what I want to do is to filter all the value, meaning if I have 2 or more items, all should be present from the filter .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If I have facility1, facility2, facility3 in the list, once my hospital have facility1 it will display even though they dont have facility 2 and 3. What I want to do is that hospital should have facility 1, 2 and 3. Base on my observation when I run the application. Can you update the filter sir that will satisify this condition

Comment: The filteredAll is not working sir , it cant detect any hospitals even I select only 1 facility , still it's not displaying

Comment: @carljohnsantos: then there is only one solution left: use your head and think about how my solutions work.

Comment: Copy sir , sorry for lots of follow up question

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = "*"; //error
```

Because we must use `ArrayList#add(Object)` method to add a value to list obj.

```
list1.add("*");//correct

theFilter[5]=(String)list1.get(0);//to get a value from list object based on given index position.
```

`ArrayList#get(int)` method to get a value from list obj.